# Microsoft Python language server not recognizing `for` loop over `zip()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, type-hinting

In the following mwe `visual studio code` seems to be unable to realize the type.
Using mouse-over shows the type of `testa` as `str` and `testb` as `float` which is correct.
Using mouse-over on `aelem` or `belem` no type is recognized.
I wonder why.

```py
import typing
def MWE(a: typing.List[str], b: typing.List[float]) -> None:
    testa=a[0]
    testb=b[0]
    print(f"{testa} und {testb}")
    for aelem, belem in zip(a,b):
        aelem.rfind("/")
        round(belem)
MWE(['a','b'], [1.0,2.0])
```

Comment: It's a bug. Please report it to https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server (this has nothing to do with mypy).

Comment: @BrettCannon I submittet as <https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1717>

Answer (score 1):

Use `round(belem)` instead of   `belem.round()`. Then, for example, `MWE(['a','b'], [1.0,2.0])` works just fine.

Most likely VSCode is having trouble identifying `belem` as a `float` because `belem.float()` is not a valid call.

But even with `belem.float()`, Pycharm identifies `belem` as a float (at runtime).[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my mistake using round. So it seems to be a visual studio problem. I change the question.